# Cannot send data with web socket in API Controller's "HttpGet" method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, websocket

### [ASP.NET] Cannot send data with web socket in API Controller's "HttpGet" method.\

- [ASP.NET] 无法在 API 控制器的 'HttpGet' 方法中使用 web socket 发送数据

> Tips: Chinese is just translation, you don't have to care about it.
> 提示: 英文仅仅是翻译, 你不需要关心他们.

Back end code
后端代码

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Null.SimpleFishing.Controllers.WS
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class WSController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async void Get()
        {
            if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                using (WebSocket webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
                {
                    await Echo(HttpContext, webSocket);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            }
        }
        private async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
            {
                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);

                result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            }
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);   # exception here
        }
    }
}
```

Front end code
前端代码

```js
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:31137/api/ws");  // front end logic is just create a WebSocket (前端逻辑仅仅是创建一个 WebSocket)
```

Exception:
异常:

> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to the response body, the response has completed.
> Object name: 'HttpResponseStream'.

But, if I write code in 'Startup.cs', and use "app.Use(processor);", it will work very well.
但是, 如果我在 'Startup.cs' 中使用这些代码, 然后用 "app.Use(逻辑代码);", 就不会有任何问题.
These code is from [MSDOCS WebSocket in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
这些代码来自 [微软文档 ASP.NET Core 中的 Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

MSDOCS said that: "When using a WebSocket, you must keep the middleware pipeline running for the duration of the connection. If you attempt to send or receive a WebSocket message after the middleware pipeline ends, you may get an exception like the following:"
微软文档写有: "使用 WebSocket 时，“必须”在连接期间保持中间件管道运行。 如果在中间件管道结束后尝试发送或接收 WebSocket 消息，可能会遇到以下异常情况："
Maybe it is because of this,,, but I don't know how to solve it.
有可能是因为这个,,, 但是我不知道该如何解决

Comment: SO require users to use English whenever ask or answer a question, pls refer to this :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

> Tips: The Chinese content is just the translation of the English content, you don't have to care about them. (Please don't remove them)
> 提示, 英文只是只是中文的翻译, 你不需要关心他们 (也请不要删掉它们)

Finally I found the solution... it's, DON'T return anything before the WebSocket was closed...
最终我找到答案了... 那就是, 不要在 WebSocket 关闭前返回任何东西...

New code:
新代码:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
    if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        using (WebSocket webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
        {
            await Echo(HttpContext, webSocket);
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new BadRequestResult();
    }
}
```

> Added ActionResult return value for this Method, if use 'void', ASP.NET may return something automatically for you, but we shouldn't return before WebSocket closed.
> 为方法添加了 ActionResult 返回值, 如果使用 'void', 那么 ASP.NET 可能会自动帮你返回点什么, 但是我们不应该在 WebSocket 关闭前返回.

> See also: [websocket api controller example](https://github.com/nosalan/websocket-api-controller-example)
> 另见: [WebSocket API控制器示例](https://github.com/nosalan/websocket-api-controller-example)